# React: How to get current Route path on each route change? React-router v5

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The following code is giving base route instead of nested routes or I can say the current route

```
function test() {
  const route = useRouteMatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(route);
  }, [route]);
}
```

I need path here like 'base/user/:id' not 'base/user/:123'

Answer (score 1):

You've got the correct hook for getting the `path` that was used when matching/rendering the route.

[`useRouteMatch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch)

> The `useRouteMatch` hook attempts to [match](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/match) the current URL in the
> same way that a `<Route>` would. It’s mostly useful for getting access
> to the match data without actually rendering a `<Route>`.

[match](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/match)

> A match object contains information about how a `<Route path>` matched
> the URL. `match` objects contain the following properties:
>
> - params - (object) Key/value pairs parsed from the URL corresponding to the dynamic segments of the path
> - isExact - (boolean) true if the entire URL was matched (no trailing characters)
> - ***path - (string) The path pattern used to match.*** Useful for building nested `<Route>`s
> - url - (string) The matched portion of the URL. Useful for building nested `<Link>`s

The `useRouteMatch` hook returns a `match` object with the `path` property that is the path used for matching.

```
<Route path="/base/user/:id" component={Test} />
```

...

```
function Test() {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(path); // "/base/user/:id"
  }, [path]);

  return null;
}
```

[image: Edit react-how-to-get-current-route-path-on-each-route-change]